# DataDog instrumentation breaks code fragment when Axios post errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, datadog

To isolate a problem I'm seeing after instrumenting an ExpressJS app with dd-trace I've moved some code out of a utility file into the mainline code.

`this.client` is an Axios instance.

This snippet works regardless of whether or not the POST is successful:

```js
return (async (fn) => {
  try {
    return Promise.resolve(await fn())
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e)
  }

  return Promise.reject(new Error('Unusual Error'))
})(() => this.client.post(`foo/bars`, data, opts))
```

With the following snippet the DD instrumentation code throws an exception and hangs if the Axios POST throws an error. (Yes, it's a single-iteration `for` loop. Work with me.)

```js
return (async (fn) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    try {
      return Promise.resolve(await fn())
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e)
    }
  }

  return Promise.reject(new Error('Unusual Error'))
})(() => this.client.post(`foo/bars`, data, opts))
```

IRL the code is incrementally trickier, but these fragments reproduce the problem.

Top snippet works w/ instrumentation for both successful and error POSTs, bottom snippet works on success, fails on error.

Not sure how to think about this. Logging doesn't help much (and is hampered w/ an indestructible health ping to boot).

I assume I'm missing something silly. I can provide additional info if needed.

The exception I've seen under some circumstances:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
  at DatadogSpan._createContext (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/opentracing/span.js:76:32)
  at new DatadogSpan (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/opentracing/span.js:30:30)
  at DatadogTracer._startSpanInternal (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/opentracing/tracer.js:73:18)
  at DatadogTracer._startSpan (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/opentracing/tracer.js:62:17)
  at DatadogTracer.Tracer.startSpan (/app/node_modules/opentracing/lib/tracer.js:61:21)
  at Object.wrapMiddleware (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/plugins/util/web.js:104:25)
  at callHandle (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/datadog-plugin-router/src/index.js:111:14)
  at wrapCallHandle (/app/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/datadog-plugin-router/src/index.js:41:14)
  at Layer.handle_error (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
  at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
```

Comment: What does "*fails on error.*" mean? Are you saying you're getting the "unusual error"?

Comment: What dd-trace plugins are you using? And is there a transpiler involved? Is this server-side code?

Comment: @Bergi All plugins are currently enabled (disabling the `express` plugin "solves" the problem, but eliminates all useful data ;) No transpiler, server-side code, some Axios interceptors but nothing that _should_ have an impact (and no trivial way to pull them out, but it's next on my list). I get no response--app goes down (or down-like) before anything happens, there's a DD exception in the logs, and Postman times out.

Comment: Sounds like a case for a bug report then. What's the exact exception you're getting in your logs? But I doubt you'll get a solution on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bergi Added the stack trace. There's a cpl other things I'll try but I'm about out. Already have a ticket open so I'm going to add a link to this question to it, and the results of my last gasp experiments. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi ... So... it started working all by itself, including the original, slightly-more-complex code. I changed nothing. Only thing I can think of is that sthng on their end changed wrt its comms back (and forth?) with the instrumentation code. I was going to try disabling the http/http2 plugins so restored the non-working code above and it worked. Restored the original code path and it worked. Four days of my life.

Comment: …and it'll come back in the worst possible moment :-/